# Does $e^{-kx} = -ke^x$?

Tags: integration

I have been working on a homework problem where I need to integrate $-ke^x dx$. I decided to factor out the $-k$ and get $e^x + C$ and then multiply $-k$ back in. However, I noticed that the back of the book gets $e^{-kx} + C$. I think that if one was to differentiate this, they would in fact get $-ke^x$, so it also seems valid, but I can't figure out the steps or rules that I would use to get this as my answer.

I can't think of any rule that I already have learned that says however that $e^{-kx}$ should equal $-ke^x$. Did I do something wrong in either of these integrations, or is this actually correct? it can make a pretty big difference when it is involved in the context of a larger problem.

Comment: Consider $k=0$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Can you please add parenthesis to your expressions? This way they are a bit confusing. Also use MathJax if you know how to do it, if not I'll edit it.

Comment: Why do you think that if one differentiated $e^{-kx}$ they would get $-ke^x$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that if you differentiate $e^{-kx}$ you get $-ke^{-kx}$, and *not* $-ke^{x}$.  If the problem is stated as $\int -k e^{x}\,dx$ then your answer of $-ke^{x} + C$ is correct.  If the problem is written as $\int -ke^{-kx}\,dx$ then the  book's answer of $e^{-kx} + C$ is correct.  My guess is you either misread the problem or there is a typo in the book somewhere.

To answer your question in the title, **no**, $e^{-kx}$ and $-ke^{x}$ are not equal in general.

Answer (score 1):

Taking $k=2$, it would mean that squaring is the same as multiplying by $2$…